# Deploy angular 2 app to github pages with custom domain

Tags: angular, github-pages

I have an angular 2 application that I created using the angular cli. I have successfully deployed it to github pages using the following command:

```
ng github-pages:deploy
```

However, when I add a custom domain to my specific github repository my application gets stuck on the "Loading..." screen. In the development console I can see that there is a routing issue going on, but I don't know what to do. My browser is looking for the following files:

```
http://my.custom.domain/<repo name>/styles.513b65c5bba3c35eb04c.bundle.css
http://my.custom.domain/<repo name>/inline.0e162e6cc8b7a5163b49.bundle.js
http://my.custom.domain/<repo name>/main.f270f3e2ae5f67b1a8e9.bundle.js
```

Any ideas why this is happening? Has anyone published their angular 2 app to github pages with a custom domain?

Comment: Did you read it how to deploy on their documentation page

Comment: Did you change the base url attribute in the angular-cli.json file?

Comment: @GabrieleB-David oh no I didn't, what should the base url be?

Comment: @BrettOberg the base url is everything after the domain name. For example, if I have a professor website at a university, the url would look like this: university.com/~gdavid/ . The base url would be '~gdavid'. Angular would automatically try to run on university.com/ without changing this property

Comment: @GabrieleB-David ahh so something like this ng github-pages:deploy --b /<repo name>/ ??

Comment: Yes, that's the idea. I haven't used angular-cli to deploy to a custom domain so I can't be sure of the flags you're using but that's the idea

Comment: Okay, thank you. I will try that